# Get distance between user's 1st degree connections?

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

How can I take two 1st degree connections and get the distance between them, to see if they are connected to one another.
So far I've managed to get the 1st degree connections list of the authorized user, but I'm issues with the distance.

Thank you.

Comment: @casperOne It's about Linkedin API, that's why the Linkedin and API tags were used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only directly determine the distance to an arbitrary user from the current user via the API using the `relation-to-viewer:(distance)` [field](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile).

You would need to get connection A to log in and pull that field for connection B to determine the distance.

Comment: So with the whole LinkedIn API, there is no way to tell if the user's 1st degree connections know each other?

Comment: Correct, there are no direct methods to do this - the only way would be to pull the connections of connection A, traverse those connections to see if connection B exists, but as the [docs state](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api), connections of connections are not available.